# How to add an sms:number link to a menu?

Tags: 8, navigation

In Drupal 8.5, when you're adding a menu item, you can add a telephone number by setting the **Link** to `tel:1-555-555-5555`.

However, if you try to add an SMS link like `sms:1-555-555-5555`, it fails validation and says "The path 'sms:1-555-555-5555` is invalid."

What's the easiest way to override this so that I can add an sms link to the menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the `sites/default/services.yml`

There is an option called `filter_protocols`

Add `sms` to it.

If file is not available, copy the file from `default.services.yml` to `services.yml`